# Stackdriver Uptime Check giving wrong percentage

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

The Uptime checks on Stackdriver monitoring is giving the wrong percentage (always 100% uptime) even when I focus the view to just the period of time when the outage occurred, is there a way to download the information in CSV format so i can get a correct value?

Comment: The problem is that you don't think the uptime checks are 100% accurate? or that you want to download (I am not sure what you want to download) something?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get the details of the uptime check via CSV file. I am not entirely sure this is possible, what I found is that you can View them using the following formats: C#, Java, Go, Node.js, etc 
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#viewing_an_uptime_check
If this is not what you are looking for, you might need to raise a Feature request here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: "The problem is that you don't think the uptime checks are 100% accurate? or that you want to download (I am not sure what you want to download) something? – grimmjow_sms Jan 24 at 16:57"

It is actually both.

Comment: It's not just you, it definitely gives the wrong percentage. I sent feedback, but no reply/result. I don't think there is a way to download the data, so we'll have to wait for GCP to fix this.

Comment: I would suggest you to raise a case to support and provide all the details needed and include screenshots. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers 
Because I fail to understand the issue here.

Comment: @JasonHinkle / todinov is there any way you can edit the post and add more details? Share some reproduction steps, screenshots, an explanation on what you see and what are you expecting? 
As on download, I think that this is not possible at the time, kindly raise a FR with the link I previously shared